Why isn't my Qt QML plugin linking against my Qt Quick App on XMake?
I have a very simple project:
add_rules("mode.debug", "mode.release")

target("mylib")
    add_rules("qt.qmlplugin")
    add_rules("utils.symbols.export_all", {export_classes = true})

    add_headerfiles("src/plugin/*.h")
    add_files("src/plugin/*.h")
    add_files("src/plugin/*.cpp")

    set_values("qt.qmlplugin.import_name", "Highlight")

target("myapp")
    add_rules("qt.quickapp")

    add_deps("mylib")
    add_files("src/main.cpp")
    add_files("src/qml.qrc")

    if is_plat("windows") then
        add_ldflags("/subsystem:console")
    end

Everything works as expected when I compile only "mylib" or when I compile only "myapp" (without "mylib" as dependency), but when I try to add the dependency I get the following linker error:
[ 90%]: linking.release myapp.exe
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.40.33807\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\link.exe" -nologo -dynamicbase -nxcompat -machine:x64 -libpath:C:\Qt\6.7.2\msvc2019_64\lib -libpath:build\windows\x64\release /opt:ref /opt:icf mylib.lib Qt6Gui.lib Qt6Quick.lib Qt6Qml.lib Qt6Core.lib Qt6Network.lib ws2_32.lib gdi32.lib ole32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib user32.lib opengl32.lib imm32.lib winmm.lib iphlpapi.lib /subsystem:console -out:build\windows\x64\release\myapp.exe build\.objs\myapp\windows\x64\release\src\main.cpp.obj build\.objs\myapp\windows\x64\release\gens\rules\qt\qrc\qml_43BBE12C.cpp.obj
error: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'mylib.lib'

The content of my build dir is as follows:
ls .\build\windows\x64\release\MyProject\

    Directory: C:\Users\user\myproject\build\windows\x64\release\MyProject

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----          01/01/2000    00:00                myproject
-a---          01/01/2000    00:00          15360 mylib.dll
-a---          01/01/2000    00:00           8884 mylib.exp
-a---          01/01/2000    00:00          14846 mylib.lib
-a---          01/01/2000    00:00            215 plugin.qmltypes

So, it means the "mylib.lib" exists.
What am I missing here?

Chat GPT 4o suggested adding add_linkdirs("$(buildir)/$(plat)/$(arch)/$(mode)/MyProject") to "myapp" and it linked, but seems like an ugly workaround
